# InDesign: Hyperlink an entire cell in tables

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, interactive, cell

Can InDesign make hyperlinks specifically to a table cell, so that link appears as soon as you hover on a cell before reaching the text in a cell?

Comment: Probably not, this is not HTML.

Comment: Theoretically, you can add an interactive button with image changing after "onmouseover" and then save it as an interactive PDF, but still it's better to do that in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not attached to the cell directly.

The easiest way is to add a **button** the size of the cell and make it *invisible*.

Just draw a rectangle over the cell, set its fill and stroke to `None`, then alter the options in `Window > Interactive > Buttons & Forms`

[image]

- The arrow and bold number above are in a table cell.
- I drew a rectangle over the cell to match it's size
- Removed the fill and stroke from the rectangle
- Set the options in the **Button Panel**
- In addition to setting the destination (URL), I changed the `Rollover` state so that the fill is black at 10% opacity
- Be certain to uncheck `Printable` in most instances.